# In Windows standard program Paint a picture do not opens via an https link from an external source in Windows server 2022

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, windows-server

Windows server is located on AWS EC2 instance.

In Paint an image opens via an https link from an external source in Windows 10 on my local computer, but does not open in Windows Server 2022 on ABC EC2 instance.

I open this picture without any problems in the Edge browser on the same AWS windows server instance1. What could be the matter? I need this I need this functionality for RPA automation.